# How to export the Eclipse plugins to a folder "eclispe" with the cotent .exlipsextension and subfolder plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Now I develop a plug-in for WindRiver workbench. When I export my plug-in, only a xx.jar file is generated. I wonder how to export my plug-in in a folder exclipes with the content ".exlipsextension" and subfolder "plugins".

Answer (score 0):

Create a product definition files, then includes your plug-ins and other required plug-ins in that product.

Then export the product

Comment: Hi, I don't want to create a product based on eclipse. Just want to export a installation package of plug-in. I thinks the export wizard only exports a .jar without other useful files, like ".eclipsextension", "plugin.xml" and ect...

Comment: .eclipseextension file is used for a product based on eclipse. "plugin.xml" and other staffs(such as .class, .properties) are packaged in the jar file if they exist in your plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I roll back to eclipse3.2, it's OK now